# Chef Bash onliner to grep the content of a file in another file

Tags: bash, chef-infra

I need to put the content of a file into another file if that content does not exists already (in a idempotent way) using chef.

The `file1.txt` has the following content:

```
subject=/DC=corp/DC=NAME/CN=COMPANY Issuing CA
issuer=/CN=COMPANY Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
fewfgwgwegarearentnsrtntrstrntnsrtntnstrntrnsrtnstrnsrtnrtnsrtnr
gregargragregrGRGrgregREGREGRGZTDNBFNFGNFGNFGNFGNBDVvhrhrehrehre
gewgreaghareherhherhhaeharehrehreahreahrehearhreahreahaerhrehher
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

subject=/CN=COMPANY Root CA
issuer=/CN=COMPANY Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
INjIVNRIVNRVINRvORIniNNknjnejvejnringringrongrognreonganaI6udddd
febwgpubgiurbguiregbeagubpaegigreaignaeingreaingeaingaeinhaddddd
findaofgbugbrluigblzriugbzrugaRIGjRIJgaprjgarigarianbnblkrnbnjna
wfefrgregeGWGWG=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The secont file is `/opt/chef/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem` where i need to put the chain from `file1.txt` if that does not already exists.

The resource i'm using is this:

```
bash 'add company cert chain to chef certs' do
  code <<-EOH
    cat /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/comp.corp.ca.chain.2018.crt >> /opt/chef/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
  EOH
not_if 'grep "$(cat /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/comp.corp.ca.chain.2018.crt)" /opt/chef/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem'
end
```

For some reason, that does not work.

Can anyone please explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Gabi

Answer (score 0):

back in the days, you could use [`Chef::Util::FileEdit`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/chef/Chef/Util/FileEdit), but it was [deprecated](https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/7043).

instead you can use other chef resources to achieve it.
 once of them is to use [`ruby_block` resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_ruby_block.html), which has all the ruby capabilites. that means that you can use the power of ruby to do it for you (don't forget to provide a `not_if` or `only_if` guards...

something like:

```
ruby_block 'concatenate files' do
  block do
    f1 = File.read('first.file')
    f2 = File.read('second.file')
    content = f1 + f2
    File.open('combined.file', 'w') { |f| f.write content }
  end
  not_if { File.read('combined.file').includes? 'some anchor text' }
end
```

another idea, is to create your desired certificate chain offline, store it in an [encrypted data bag](https://docs.chef.io/data_bags.html#encrypt-a-data-bag-item), and use your recipe to place it on the node.

Comment: First of all, thank you. But my problem is that `some anchor text` which is something somehow dynamically.

Comment: i've added another idea to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to compare the two files,

```
not_if 'cmp /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/sdl.corp.ca.chain.2018.crt /opt/chef/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem'
```

Attempting to use `grep` for this is weird and complex.

If you want to verify that `file1` exists as a subfile of `file2`, doing that strictly probably requires a simple Awk script or similar.

```
awk 'BEGIN { rc=1 }
    NR == FNR { k[++i] = $0; next }
    k[j+1] == $0 { j++ }
    j > i { rc=0; nextfile }
    k[j] =! $0 { j = 0 }
    END { exit rc }' file1 file2
```

(Ad hoc; not properly tested.)

Comment: Thank you! But I cannot compare them as the two files will always be different. the first has what the second should get if it doesn't already have it. Is there something I miss from your explanation?

Comment: Not really; it was just not clear from your explanation whether the files should be identical or what the condition should be for requiring the file to be installed again.

Answer (score 0):

The SOLUTION was actually much simpler and it was given to me by one of my colleagues.
There's no need to compare some strings or the existence of a variable in a file or nothing like that.
The condition is simple, just

```
not_if "knife ssl check <url>".
```

Answer (score -1):

I would rewrite this a little bit.

```
needle=$(cat /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/sdl.corp.ca.chain.2018.crt)

if ! grep -Fxq "$needle" /opt/chef/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
then
    $(cat /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/comp.corp.ca.chain.2018.crt >> /opt/chef/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem)
fi
```

Comment: Just FYI, this is a very complex grep.  I would suggest maybe grabbing the first line of the signature and searching for that.  The likelihood of collision would be tiny.

Comment: The command substitution around the `cat` is an error, though vaguely harmless. You are taking the output of `cat` and executing it as a new command, but since there is no output -- because you are redirecting all the output to a file -- there is no command to execute. You will merely get an inefficient subprocess which does nothing.

Comment: `grep` on a newline-separated multi-line string happens to work, but doesn't do what you expect. This is equivalent to (but less efficient than) `grep -Fxqf /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/sdl.corp.ca.chain.2018.crt /opt/chef/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem`  i.e. if the files have at least one line in common, there will be a match.

Comment: Appreciate it.  I assume there was some errors, as I didn't actually test it and hand jammed it.  Was hoping that the concept was correct though.